# NullPointerException when startActivity from JAR file

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar

I have a child project that must be included in parent project.
What I did:

1. Mark child as library and compile
2. Took resulted .jar and put it in \libs folder from a parent
   project.
3. Copied all res used in child project in parent \res folder.
4. Add .JAR file in Properties->Java Build Path->libraries.
5. Call StartActivity from parent project to an activity from child
   project.

After running parent project it crashes. Callstack says that is NullPointerException on:

```
final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
layout .setOnClickListener(this);
```

This means that layout is null.

I should mention that running a child project as a single project works perfectly.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Stupid comment: I guess that the space between `layout` and `.setOnClickListener(this);` is just a typing error, right?

Comment: make child project a library project and reference the same in parent project. if using eclipse http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html

Comment: Yes, it was typed manually not copy/pasted from code. And I did that reference in parent project.

Comment: Make sure you have a layout with such Id and that thr R you imported is the correct one.

Comment: I verified it. It exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use a .jar file if you "child" project depends on resources files. You need to import your project as a library (with source code) instead.

1. Copy your child project (all source code + resources) into your parent project libs/your_child_project_name/ directory
2. Setup your build system (Gradle or Ant) to use the third party library
3. Check for dependencies conflicts (i.e both child and parent use the android support .Jar file, in that case remove the one in the child project and use the one in the parent project)
4. Rebuild your parent project
5. Now you can import from the child project